# JavaScript string with regex search

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a returned string consisting of multiple classes:

```
"xxx1sbu xxx2sdf xxx1sef xxx1sb1 xxx1su xxx1s1 dxxx1s xxx1sdfg xxx1sbf"
```

I need the regex to search the string and find the classes based on the following criteria:

1) class begins with 'xxx1s'

2) class is no longer than 7 characters (letters and numbers) excluding a following space ('xxx1sbu')

3) if a space follows the class ('xxx1sbu ') then it is also found so that it can be removed.

I then use the regex to replace the found classes to

```
var classesReplaced = classesString.replace(regex, "")
```

The string should then look as follows:

```
"xxx2sdf dxxx1s xxx1sdfg"
```

So far the best I have come up with is:

```
RegExp: /\bxxx1s([a-z1-9])([a-z1-9])(\s)|\bxxx1s([a-z1-9])([a-z1-9])\b/g
pattern: \bxxx1s([a-z1-9])([a-z1-9])(\s)|\bxxx1s([a-z1-9])([a-z1-9])\b
```

I also tried to use javascript to build the expression but it keeps stripping off the '\b':

```
var classId = 'xxx1s';
var regex2 = new RegExp('\b'+ classId +'([a-z1-9])([a-z1-9])(\s)|\b'+ classId +'([a-z1-9])([a-z1-9])\b','g');
```

Is there a better way to write this?? My understanding of regex isn't great!

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hmm... sounds like something along the lines of `\W(xxx1s\S{0,2})\s?`.  What are you using `\b` for?

Comment: @abiessu why not put as ans? `\S` should be `\w` here

Comment: From what I understand it matches a whitespace or the beginning/end of a string. Didn't know whether I needed it or not!

Comment: Why don't you want to remove the "xxx1sbf" at the end? It seems to match your pattern of items to remove.

Comment: @jkshah: I thought about it, but I didn't want to put such a short answer without making sure the `\b` didn't matter...

Comment: @JoeDeRose Thanks for the answer, it works perfectly. Plus your explanation makes this whole regex thing easier to understand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the command and regex you need:

```
NewString = OldString.replace( /\bxxx1s\S{0,2}\b\s?/, "" );
```

Here's how that breaks down:

- `\b` is the opening word border for the section you want to replace.
- `xxx1s` is the base text you want to remove.
- `\S{0,2}` (upper-case S) finds any non-white-space between 0 and 2 characters long; added to the item above, it makes sure that only items of 7 or fewer characters are found.
- `\b` is the closing word border.
- `\s?` (lower-case s) finds the trailing space; the `?` makes it optional so the last item in the series won't be skipped.

Comment: Looks good, but you missed global match modifier, then it should be: `var classesReplaced = classesString.replace(/\bxxx1s\S{0,2}\b\s?/g, "");`

Comment: This solved the problem perfectly! I have been using it throughout my web app ever since. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regex you should use:

```
var regex = /((?:\s*(xxx1s)\w{1,2})(?=\W))|(xxx1sbu )/g;
```

Comment: Your regex will make a mistake for 'xxxx1sbu ', since it will remove text that does not match the criteria